# GEOS-Chem compilation error and then Segmentation fault

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, compiler-errors, fortran, gfortran

```
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "2ubuntu1"
(Missing operator before ubuntu1?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "2ubuntu1"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
make[5]: Entering directory `/home/caecivil10/Desktop/GC_V11-01/Code.v11-01/HEMCO'
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "2ubuntu1"
(Missing operator before ubuntu1?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near "2ubuntu1"
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
make[6]: Entering directory `/home/caecivil10/Desktop/GC_V11-01/Code.v11-01/HEMCO/Core'
ar crs libHCO.a hco_arr_mod.o hco_calc_mod.o hco_chartools_mod.ohco_clock_mod.o hco_config_mod.o hco_datacont_mod.o hco_diagn_mod.o hco_driver_mod.o hco_emislist_mod.o hco_error_mod.o hco_extlist_mod.o hco_filedata_mod.o hco_fluxarr_mod.o hco_geotools_mod.o hco_interp_mod.o hcoio_dataread_mod.o hcoio_diagn_mod.o hcoio_messy_mod.o hcoio_read_esmf_mod.o hcoio_read_std_mod.o hcoio_write_esmf_mod.o hcoio_write_std_mod.o hco_logfile_mod.o hco_readlist_mod.o hco_restart_mod.o hco_state_mod.o hco_tidx_mod.o hco_timeshift_mod.o hco_types_mod.o hco_unit_mod.o hco_vertgrid_mod.o messy_ncregrid_base.o messy_ncregrid_mpi.o
mv libHCO.a ../../lib
make[6]: Leaving directory `/home/caecivil10/Desktop/GC_V11-01/Code.v11-01/HEMCO/Core'
make[5]: Leaving directory `/home/caecivil10/Desktop/GC_V11-01/Code.v11-01/HEMCO'
```

When ever I am running a code for compilation using make I am getting above error.

I execute:
    make help
    make -j2 all MET=geosfp GRID=4x5 COMPILER=gfortran OMP=no

then I am getting above error but the compilation is not terminated. it creates an executable but after running the executable it shows:

```
*************   S T A R T I N G   4 x 5   G E O S--C H E M   *************
Using GMAO GEOS-FP met fields
#######################################
# OPENMP TURNED OFF FOR TESTING!!!    #
#######################################

===> SIMULATION START TIME: 2017/04/05 15:47 <===

==============================================================================   =
G E O S - C H E M   U S E R   I N P U T
READ_INPUT_FILE: Reading input.geos
===============================================================================
GEOS-CHEM I/O ERROR     2 in file unit    11
Encountered at routine:location read_input_file:1
===============================================================================

Program received signal SIGSEGV: Segmentation fault - invalid memory reference.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F84A95F9777
#1  0x7F84A95F9D7E
#2  0x7F84A8D35CAF
#3  0x9173FD in __hco_driver_mod_MOD_hco_final at hco_driver_mod.F90:308
#4  0x72C0AB in __hcoi_gc_main_mod_MOD_hcoi_gc_final at hcoi_gc_main_mod.F90:748
#5  0x4681AD in cleanup_ at cleanup.F:276
#6  0x999C80 in __error_mod_MOD_geos_chem_stop at error_mod.F:758
#7  0x5E5706 in __input_mod_MOD_read_input_file at input_mod.F:283 (discriminator 1)
#8  0x5F6FF0 in geos_chem at main.F:486
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: If you think the problem is in a Makefile, you must show the Makefile. To debug the other error we would need to see the code. But the code should be compiled with some debugging flags.

Comment: Please don't beg for urgent assistance. This is a volunteer site. If you need urgent help, you need to find professional support (but not here!) and pay for it.

Comment: The input files for the GC to run are missing. Please find out more in the HEMCO log file which will be generated while executing the executable (geos.mp).